# Skip Sunday when calculating next 4 days from current date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to calculate next 4 days from current day, but I need to skip Sunday.

How can I do this in JavaScript with Moment.js?

```html
<ul>
  <li>moment().format('ddd')</li>
  <li>moment().add(1, 'days').format('ddd')</li>
  <li>moment().add(2, 'days').format('ddd')</li>
  <li>moment().add(3, 'days').format('ddd')</li>
  <li>moment().add(4, 'days').format('ddd')</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var noOfDays = 8;

for(var i=1;i<=noOfDays;i++){
 var date = moment().add(i, 'days');
 
 if( date.day()==0 ) noOfDays++;
 else
 console.log(date.format('ddd'))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Check if day number is 0, then skip it.